# Unable to change Avatar image, "service unavailable"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is sort of a meta-question. Everytime I try to upload a Avatar image to ROS Answers, I get

```
 Service unavailable

This service is currently unavailable.

If you have any questions, please contact the site administrator at 
admin@answers.ros.org
```

This has been the case everytime I tried in the last few months. I also tried writing a mail to the suggested email address multiple times, but only get a mail with the following back:

```
<<< 554 5.7.1 <admin@answers.ros.osuosl.org>: Relay access denied
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
<<< 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issues are appreciated. I know this isn´t exactly a ROS related question, but I feel I tried hard enough warranting asking here by now ;)

/edit: Incidentally, just got the "service unavailable" message when posting this question again. That of course looks like posting the question didn´t work at first, which is the reason we see double postings on this site occassionally.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87351/unable-to-change-avatar-image,-%22service-unavailable%22/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2013-10-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would be good to file as an issue here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues?state=open

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-10-04**:
Indeed, haven't seen that before. Will do.